# Button for opening new jFrame in netbeans not working

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, compiler-errors

I'm trying to make an edit button in my main jFrame that will open the editing jFrame that I have created already. To do this, I wrote the code:

```
private void btEditActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    new IAedit().setVisible(true);
}
```

However, the class name 'IAedit' and the method 'setVisible' is showing in italics and I know it's not supposed to do so. When clicking the button, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: <any>.setVisible
at ia.IAmain.btEditActionPerformed(IAmain.java:82)
at ia.IAmain.access$000(IAmain.java:12)
at ia.IAmain$1.actionPerformed(IAmain.java:42)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82
```

The weirder thing is that I have another button in the IAmain class which opens another jFrame perfectly fine with the exact same code. Please help me. Thanks :)

Comment: 1) `Uncompilable source code` Don't try to run source code that has compilation errors. Fix them first! 2) See [The use of multiple frames, good/bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556). (Bad!)

Comment: alright thank you :)

Comment: Never try to run code that doesn't compile. Makes no sense.

Answer (score -1):

I would advise you use an ActionListener on the button; then inside of the action listener create a new frame and set it to visible

Comment: thank you. this is my first time making a GUI so how exactly do you do what you said?

Comment: @Ranjani: by reading the Swing tutorials, something you should already be doing.